# Why is my StreamReader string empty when referenced outside of the containing class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamreader

I'm using a StreamReader to fill a string up with data from a web response. This works just fine, and can be accessed inside the class. (WebResponseEventArgs) When I try to access it elsewhere however, it returns an empty string. Not null, just an empty string.

WebResponseEventArgs class:

```
public class WebResponseEventArgs : EventArgs 
{

public WebAsync WebAsyncObject;

public string ErrorMessage;

public JArray ValidationErrors;

public JArray Data;

public string ResponseString;

public string Test;

public StreamReader reader;

public WebResponseEventArgs(WebAsync webAsync)
{

    Test = "Hello!";

    WebAsyncObject = webAsync;

    Stream responseStream = WebAsyncObject.requestState.webResponse.GetResponseStream ();
    reader = new StreamReader (responseStream);
    ResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd ();

    if(ResponseString != "")
    {

        try {

            Debug.Log (ResponseString);

            Data = JArray.Parse (ResponseString);


        }
        catch(JsonReaderException e)
        {
            Data = JArray.Parse ("[" + ResponseString + "]");
        }

        if(Data.Contains ("errors"))
        {
            ValidationErrors = (JArray) Data["errors"];
        }


        Debug.Log (Data[1]);

    }

}

public bool HasErrors()
{
    if(ErrorMessage != null) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}



}
```

As you can see I'm logging the string in the debugger, and it shows me the complete response string, verifying that it does work inside this class. When the variable is called from anywhere else however, it returns an empty string. I spent the past 2 hours Googling and hoping someone else had stumbled upon this issue before, but I couldn't find anything.

Here is the event handler that tries to access the string:

```
public void OnGetAllResource(WebResponseEventArgs e)
{

    //Check for errors

    if(e.HasErrors())
    {
        Debug.Log (e.ErrorMessage);
        return;
    }

    //Debug.Log (r);

    //Test our resource inherited class

    else
    {

        //string string2 = Shift.Instance.getAll ();


        //string string3 = Shift.Instance.getAll ();

        //Start composing our list

        Debug.Log (e.Test);

        Debug.Log (e.ResponseString);
```

Debug.Log(e.Test) works fine, Debug.Log(e.ResponseString) returns an empty string.

I hope someone can help me with this, it's been causing me a major headache :)

Comment: Where is your code you access it *outside of the containing class?* see http://sscce.org/

Comment: Especially read the *golden rule* http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @EZI How could I improve my question? I feel that it seems quite descriptive and clear, and the tags provide context.

Comment: Tristan, First of all, There is no such thing like *"a public variable gives different results depending on where you read it"*. So to find your bug, I don't think you give us enough context. How about creating a SSCCE so that when we copy and paste we can regenerate your problem. I am sure you will find your bug yourself while you are preparing it.

Comment: EZI is correct. This question is poorly written and does not offer enough information for someone else to answer it. That said, it's possible (likely, even) that if you were to follow better design practices, like using read-only properties for the `EventArgs` subclass members instead of writeable fields, this bug wouldn't exist. You've probably got some code somewhere else that assigns a new, empty string value to the field. Change the `WebResponseEventArgs` so that it does a good job protecting its own data, and you will probably get a compiler error telling you exactly where your bug is.

Comment: Change this field declaration public string ResponseString; to a property with a backing field and breakpoint the Setter. Though this alone: Data = JArray.Parse (ResponseString); looks like a likely culprit. Show us that Parse method.

Comment: I solved my issue by having a close look at when my web-response event was being thrown, and I noticed that on the first instantiation it worked fine, but on the second usage the string was empty. This is because I'm reusing it's main argument. (WebAsync webAsync) This object contains a webResponse of which the stream can only be read once, explaining why it returns an empty string every other time. By moving the string assignment to the webAsync class my problem was solved. Should I post this as an answer? Thanks again for your time commenters, got some good advice.